# i can't find the sourcelist in cornerstone anymore

Tags: cornerstone

I can't find the source list in cornerstone anymore. I have tried the `View>show Source list`, but still can't find the source list. And I have tried reinstalling the software, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

1. kill CornerStone process
2. Delete config file 
   Users —>  Library   —> Preferences, there is com.zennaware.Cornerstone.plist  file（Cornerstone UI config file） 
   then delete this file
3. Restart machine

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have tried what you said but not work TT

Answer (score 0):

I moved this Library folder below away to resolve the issue. Make sure you take a backup of your Registration key first from within the app (Cornerstone -> License Information)!

~/Library/Containers/com.zennaware.cornerstone3/Data/Library